# LWUIT Ports, Blackberry and Android

Tags: android, blackberry, java-me, porting, lwuit

What approach would be better for developing on Blackberry and Android (native or porting). I tried porting LWUIT to blackberry and i did not find it easy, so many errors on the phone. Any help on succesfully porting LWUIT app to blackberry without the errors showing on the phone is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very easy to use LWUIT with Blackberry. LWUIT 1.5 having RIM.jar for Blackberry development. Just download the [LWUIT 1.5](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/lwuit/index.html) and use this for blackberry development. Some sample Blackberry application also available on that LWUIT 1.5 package.

Comment: K @bharath, i will give it another try. Do you use netbeans or the JDE ?

Comment: Netbeans is better for blackberry and Eclipse is better for Android.

Comment: Thanks @bharath, i have successfully ported to BB, its only hard the first time. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Check out Thorstens [Android port](http://www.pader-sync.com/lwuit-for-blackberry-and-android.html) he also has a RIM port but I recommend using our official RIM port from SVN. As Baharath mentioned in his post.

Answer (score 0):

You can now look at CodeNameOne which is a bright prospect of WORA(Write once Run Everywhere).